# Error getting a token price too low

Tags: tokens, web3.py, bsc, price

I have the function below that gets the value of a token on the BSC network, but when the token has a very low value, Ex: $0.0000002010 the function cannot get the correct value of the token, it returns something like 325456.1223123, I already looked for some solution but I didn't find anything.. does anyone know what happens?

```
BUSD = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56")  # BUSD
ABI = "{...}"
sellAbi = "{...}"
CAKE_ROUTER_V2 = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e')
def ver_preco3(self, token_to_buy):
    try:
        token = web3.toChecksumAddress(token_to_buy)
        sellTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(token, abi=sellAbi)
        symbol = sellTokenContract.functions.symbol().call()

        CAKE_FACTORY_V2 = web3.eth.contract(address=CAKE_ROUTER_V2, abi=ABI).functions.factory().call()
        pair = web3.eth.contract(address=CAKE_FACTORY_V2, abi=ABI).functions.getPair(token, BUSD).call()
        pair_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pair, abi=ABI)

        # Calculate Reserves of token a & b
        reserves = pair_contract.functions.getReserves().call()
        valor = reserves[1] / reserves[0]

        str_format = "{:." + self.decs_usd + "f}"
        return float(str_format.format(valor)), symbol, ""
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"ver_preco:EX: {ex}")
        return 0, "", str(ex)
```

Example of tokens getting the correct value:

0x00e1656e45f18ec6747f5a8496fd39b50b38396d

0x59f6b2435cd1421f409907ad2d9f811849ca555f

0xde301D6a2569aEfcFe271B9d98f318BAee1D30a4

0xaf44400a99a9693bf3c2e89b02652babacc5cdb9

0x0ecaf010fc192e2d5cbeb4dfb1fee20fbd733aa1

Example of token with wrong value:

0x3b3691d4c3ec75660f203f41adc6296a494404d0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all the tokens

- you said that have correct value have 18 decimals
- however the token that is showing wrong value shows that it has 0 decimals

Wrong Value Token Smart Contract Code Shows :

- https://bscscan.com/address/0x3b3691d4c3ec75660f203f41adc6296a494404d0#code

```
    string private _symbol = 'CATS';
    uint8 private _decimals = 0;
```

that must have been the reason why u were dealing with wrong value :>

Comment: So what would be the way to get the value of this token?

Comment: i advise that you shouldn't and tell the team behind this token that they are not following the erc-20 token standard